# Extract a C/C++ header file from a C# class exposed to COM

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, header-files

I'm not sure I've setup everything I've needed to in my C# class to properly, but it does work in COM. I've been looking for an example of a C# class that was successfully used in a C/C++ project, but haven't come across anything.

I've tried using the OLE/COM Object View app to open the .tlb file and save as .h, but it gives some errors: MIDL1009: unknown argument ignored; MIDL1001: cannot open input file Studio

"Studio" isn't the name of the file, it's Syslog, so that raises a red flag to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `tlb` you do not need a header file. `#import` of the tlb will generate it for you automatically.

```
#import "my.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
```

See more about `#import` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you have already exposed your C# class to COM, then you should be using COM interop to access the COM Callable Wrapper from your C++ code.

There is no need to try and generate a header file.

If you have the option of running managed code in your C++ project, then you don't even need COM, you can just reference your C# class directly and access it like you would any other .NET object from C++.